# Scrolling a CalendarView and a ListView together

Tags: android, scroll

I want to scroll entire page which contain Calendar view and list view. how to add scroll view in that. thank you in advance.

Comment: Use NestedScrollView.

Comment: Easier option! As RecyclerView supports multiple view types, you can add your CalendarView as one of the RecyclerView items. This library can help you: https://github.com/aminography/PrimeAdapter